# Circular profiles on the hallow sphere in Autodesk Inventor

Tags: autocad, autodesk, mechanicalturk, solidworks, autodesk-inventor

I am currently working on a project where I need to create the Circular profiles on the hallow sphere in Autodesk Inventor, but I am unable to create the Profiles on the sphere.

I tried creating planes and axis to draw the profiles, but due to hollow I am unable to create. Please provide a feasible solution and help me to figure out the issue.

Comment: Please if your question is not about programming, ask your question in a more appropriate forum.  For example here https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-forum/bd-p/78